# w3c validator error - p tag error

Tags: html, wordpress, w3c-validation

I receive this error on w3c validator

"No p element in scope but a p end tag seen."

cript>

Butt In my code No end tag is present

Also Get this error

"Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
From line 277, column 6774; to line 277, column 6796
ar">#conte"

Here is my code

```
<div style="margin: 10px 0 50px; float: left;">[one_fourth]
<a href="https://midwesttinting.com/automotive-window-tinting/" target="_blank">
</a><a href="https://midwesttinting.com/automotive-window-tinting/" target="_blank"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-4713 size-full" src="https://midwesttinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/autotint.png" alt="Auto Window Tint Service Kansas City" width="160" height="160" /></a>
<div style="float: left; text-align: center;">
<h3 style="margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 0;"><a title="Auto" href="#">Auto</a></h3>
<p style="float: left; text-align: left;">Midwest Tinting offers a full line of automotive window tinting films, all of which can help reject up to 99% of the sun's damaging ultraviolet rays.
[read_more text="Read More About Auto Window Tint" title="Auto Window Tint" url="http://midwesttinting.com/automotive-window-tinting/" align="right"]</p>

</div>
[/one_fourth]
[one_fourth]
<a href="https://midwesttinting.com/home-business-tint/" target="_blank"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-4718 size-full" src="https://midwesttinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/home.png" alt="Home Window Tint Service Kansas City" width="160" height="160" /></a>
<div style="float: left; text-align: center;">
<h3 style="margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 0;"><a title="Home" href="#">Home</a></h3>
<p style="float: left; text-align: left;">Whether your objective is to enhance beauty, increase comfort, increase security, or decrease utility costs, professionally installed window tint can help.
[read_more text="Read More About Home Window Tint" title="Home Window Tint" url="http://midwesttinting.com/home-business-tint/" align="right"]</p>

</div>
[/one_fourth]
[one_fourth]
<a href="https://midwesttinting.com/home-business-tint/" target="_blank"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-4716 size-full" src="https://midwesttinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/business.png" alt="Business Window Tint Service Kansas City" width="160" height="160" /></a>
<div style="float: left; text-align: center;">
<h3 style="margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 0;"><a title="Business Window Tint" href="#">Business</a></h3>
<p style="float: left; text-align: left;">Save money! Glass windows and doors represent the most critical area of heat gain in the summer and heat loss for your business in the winter.
[read_more text="Read More About Business Window Tint" title="Business Window Tint" url="http://midwesttinting.com/home-business-tint/" align="right"]</p>

</div>
[/one_fourth]
[one_fourth_last]
<a href="https://midwesttinting.com/paint-protection/" target="_blank"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-4717 size-full" src="https://midwesttinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/paint.png" alt="Auto Paint Protection Kansas City" width="160" height="160" /></a>
<div style="float: left; text-align: center;">
<h3 style="margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 0;"><a title="Paint Protection" href="#">Paint Protection</a></h3>
<p style="float: left; text-align: left;">Midwest Tinting proudly offers factory trained installation of XPEL Paint Protection Film – a virtually invisible shield that prevents damage to your vehicle.
[read_more text="Read More About Paint Protection" title="XPEL Paint Protection" url="http://midwesttinting.com/xpel-paint-protection/" align="right"]</p>

</div>
[/one_fourth_last]

[clear]
[content_block bg_image="" max_bg_width="yes" bg_fixed="no" bg_position="center bottom" bg_repeat="repeat-x" parallax_scroll="no" bg_color="#293037" content_padding="30px 0 0" font_color="#FFFFFF" class="we-are-passionate-block"]
<div style="text-align: center;">
<h4 style="margin-bottom: 25px;"><span style="font-size: 36px; color: #fd7800; line-height: 1.2;">Need a team you can count on? Look no further!</span></h4>
<h5 style="margin-bottom: 20px;"><span style="font-size: 20px; color: #999999; line-height: 1.5;">Midwest Tinting's staff is the best around. We've been in the business since 1975 and continue to be #1 in customer service, product offering and workmanship.</span></h5>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 1.2em; color: #a9a9a9;">
<div class="one_half">
<h4 style="margin-bottom: 15px; color: #ffffff !important;"><strong>Why choose us?</strong></h4>
<ul class="list-2" style="color: #999999; font-size: 17px !important; margin-top: 20px;">
    <li>Our people are the best</li>
    <li>Our products are the best</li>
    <li>We take pride in our craft</li>
    <li>We stand behind every installation</li>
    <li>Awesome warranties</li>
    <li>International Window Film Association Accreditations
<ul>
    <li>Brian - Master Accreditation Holder</li>
    <li>Caleb - Master Accreditation Holder</li>
    <li>Ron - Solar Control Specialist Accreditation Holder &amp; Automotive Film Specialist Accreditation Holder</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="one_half last_column" style="margin-bottom: 0;"><a href="https://midwesttinting.com/about-midwest-tinting/"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-4853 size-full" src="https://midwesttinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/mwtteampic.png" alt="Midwest Tinting Window Tint Service" width="500" height="333" /></a></div>
</div>
[/content_block]
[content_block bg_image="" max_bg_width="yes" bg_fixed="yes" bg_position="center bottom" bg_repeat="no-repeat" parallax_scroll="no" bg_color="#ffffff" content_padding="40px 0 40px" font_color="#777777"]
<div style="text-align: center;">
<h4 style="margin: 35px 0 25px;"><span style="font-size: 34px; color: #777777; line-height: 1.2;">Find Our Listings!</span></h4>
<h5><span style="font-size: 18px; color: #999999; line-height: 1.5;">We care what our customers think! Here are some places we frequent on the web. We'd love to hear your thoughts, too!</span></h5>
</div>
[clear]
[one_third]
<div style="margin-top: 30px;">

<a href="http://www.iwfa.com"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-4557 size-medium" src="https://midwesttinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/IWFA-Revised-Logo-color-300x175.jpg" alt="International Window Film Association" width="300" height="175" /></a>

</div>
[/one_third]

[one_third]
<div style="margin-top: 30px;">

<a href="http://www.angieslist.com/companylist/us/ks/mission/midwest-tinting-reviews-115841.htm"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-4556" src="https://midwesttinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/SSA_Logo_250x250.png" alt="Angie's List Certified Midwest Tinting" width="200" height="200" /></a>

</div>
[/one_third]

[one_third_last]
<div style="margin-top: 30px;">

<a title="Click for the Business Review of Midwest Tinting, Inc., an Auto Service - Window Tinting in Shawnee Mission KS" href="http://www.bbb.org/kansas-city/business-reviews/auto-service-window-tinting/midwest-tinting-inc-in-shawnee-mission-ks-88060017#sealclick"><img class="alignnone" style="border: 0px;" src="https://seal-kansascity.bbb.org/seals/blue-seal-293-61-midwesttintinginc-88060017.png" alt="Midwest Tinting, Inc. is a BBB Accredited Business. Click for the BBB Business Review of this Auto Service - Window Tinting in Shawnee Mission KS" width="293" height="61" /></a>

</div>
[/one_third_last]
<div style="float: left; display: block; height: 15px;"></div>
[/content_block]
[clear]
[content_block bg_image="https://midwesttinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/parallax-bg.jpg" max_bg_width="yes" bg_fixed="yes" bg_position="center bottom" bg_repeat="no-repeat" parallax_scroll="no" bg_color="#24292E" content_padding="50px 0 55px" font_color="#EEEEEE"]
<div style="text-align: center;">
<h4 style="margin-bottom: 20px;"><span style="font-size: 38px; color: #fff; line-height: 1;">Customer Reviews:</span></h4>
<h4 style="margin-bottom: 20px;"><span style="font-size: 24px; color: #fff; line-height: 1;">Join the <span style="color: #f95700;">thousands </span>of happy Midwest Tinting customers and see why they <span style="color: #f95700;">love</span> us so much!</span></h4>
<h5 style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><span style="font-size: 20px; color: #999; line-height: 1.5;"><em>"We spoke with Midwest Tinting on the phone and they were very helpful about explaining their product in detail. We were able to get an appointment within 24 hours. The process took about an hour and we left our car and came back later. VERY PLEASED with the professional job and the great look of the car! Midwest also gave us detailed instructions on the care of the windows."</em></span>  <span style="color: #ffffff; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; font-size: 85%;">-- Angie's List Review</span></h5>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;"><a href="http://midwesttinting.com/testimonials/"><span style="font-size: 16px; font-style: italic;">More Customer Reviews...</span></a></div>
[/content_block]
<div style="margin-bottom: -35px;">
<p style="text-align: center;">[content_block bg_color="#FD7800" max_bg_width="yes" content_padding="35px 0" font_color="#FFFFFF" class="custom-padding"][slickr-flickr tag="autotint" thumbnail_size="small" align="center" descriptions="on" items="8"]</p>

<h3 style="margin: 10px 0px; line-height: 1.2; color: #ffffff; font-size: 27px !important; text-align: center !important;">What Are You Waiting For? Get a Quote TODAY!</h3>
[flat_button text="Contact Midwest Tinting" title="Get A Quote!" url="http://midwesttinting.com/contact/" padding="15px 20px" bg_color="transparent" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="2px" text_color="#FFFFFF" text_size="16px" align="center" target="_blank"]
[/content_block]

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your html, not wordpress code. And don't post code from the inspector, go to the page you're validating, click view source and then paste the part of the code that is problematic. The error `Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context`, happens if you put a block element (paragraph) in an inline one (span) for instance. So be sure not to have that.

Comment: _p end tag_ means `</p>`.

Comment: I am really new in wordpress. How I get the html part in wordpress?

Comment: @dingo_d I want to resolve error in wordpress

Comment: The validator doesn't go through your wordpress, it goes through your HTML ;)

Comment: And I post the code above that have error in it 
Butt At the end of <a> there is no </p> present in the code butt error is appearing that end tag is present butt there is not end tag in code

Comment: So How I will Find the html code in wordpress site???

Comment: @syck I know Butt this is not present in the code Butt validator showing the error

Comment: You find the html code in your browser.... Ctrl+U is your friend.

Comment: Ok I see the view source code of my page  So how i will edit it online on wordpress ?

Comment: Error Solved by removing the space between </a> and <div> ..... Thanks friends for help